# JSONObject error in my app

Tags: java, android, json

Trying to use a taxi booking app that was created for me, throwing an error when trying to register a user. Error is:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 501 at error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at in.techware.lataxi.net.parsers.RegistrationParser.parseRegistrationResponse(RegistrationParser.java:25)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at in.techware.lataxi.net.invokers.RegistrationInvoker.invokeRegistrationWS(RegistrationInvoker.java:42)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at in.techware.lataxi.net.WSAsyncTasks.RegistrationTask.doInBackground(RegistrationTask.java:27)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at in.techware.lataxi.net.WSAsyncTasks.RegistrationTask.doInBackground(RegistrationTask.java:12)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-05 01:59:32.079 in.techware.lataxi W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here are the parser files:

RegistrationParser.java snippet

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import in.techware.lataxi.app.App;
import in.techware.lataxi.model.AuthBean;


public class RegistrationParser {

    public AuthBean parseRegistrationResponse(String wsResponseString) {

        AuthBean authBean = new AuthBean();

        JSONObject jsonObj = null;

        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(wsResponseString);


            if (jsonObj.has("error")) {
                JSONObject errorJSObj;
                try {
                    errorJSObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("error");
                    if (errorJSObj != null) {
                        if (errorJSObj.has("message")) {
                            authBean.setErrorMsg(errorJSObj.optString("message"));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                authBean.setStatus("error");
            }
            if (jsonObj.has("status")) {
                authBean.setStatus(jsonObj.optString("status"));
                if (jsonObj.optString("status").equals("error")) {
                    if (jsonObj.has("message")) {
                        authBean.setErrorMsg(jsonObj.optString("message"));
                    } else {
                        authBean.setErrorMsg("Something Went Wrong. Please Try Again Later!!!");
                    }
                }
                if (jsonObj.optString("status").equals("500")) {
                    if (jsonObj.has("error")) {
                        authBean.setErrorMsg(jsonObj.optString("error"));
                    }
                }
                if (jsonObj.optString("status").equals("404")) {
                    if (jsonObj.has("error")) {
                        authBean.setErrorMsg(jsonObj.optString("error"));
                    }
                }
                if (jsonObj.has("message")) {
                    authBean.setErrorMsg(jsonObj.optString("message"));
                }
                if (jsonObj.optString("status").equals("notfound"))
                    authBean.setErrorMsg("Email Not Found");
                if (jsonObj.optString("status").equals("invalid"))
                    authBean.setErrorMsg("Password Is Incorrect");
            }
            try {
                if (jsonObj.has("message")) {
                    authBean.setWebMessage(jsonObj.optString("message"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (jsonObj.has("data")) {
                JSONObject dataObj = jsonObj.optJSONObject("data");
                if (dataObj != null) {
                    try {

                        if (dataObj.has("token")) {
                            authBean.setAuthToken(dataObj.optString("token"));
                        }
                        if (dataObj.has("auth_token")) {
                            authBean.setAuthToken(dataObj.optString("auth_token"));
                        }
                        if (dataObj.has("user")) {
                            JSONObject userObj = dataObj.optJSONObject("user");

                            if (userObj != null) {
                                if (userObj.has("auth_token")) {
                                    authBean.setAuthToken(userObj.optString("auth_token"));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("username")) {
                                    authBean.setUserName(userObj.optString("username"));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("user_id")) {
                                    authBean.setUserID(userObj.optString("user_id"));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("id")) {
                                    authBean.setUserID(userObj.optString("id"));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("profile_photo")) {
                                    authBean.setProfilePhoto(App.getImagePath(userObj.optString("profile_photo")));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("name")) {
                                    authBean.setName(userObj.optString("name"));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("phone")) {
                                    authBean.setPhone(userObj.optString("phone"));
                                }
                                if (userObj.has("email")) {
                                    authBean.setEmail(userObj.optString("email"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return authBean;
    }
}
```

RegistrationInvoker.java

```
package in.techware.lataxi.net.invokers;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import in.techware.lataxi.model.AuthBean;
import in.techware.lataxi.net.ServiceNames;
import in.techware.lataxi.net.WebConnector;
import in.techware.lataxi.net.parsers.RegistrationParser;
import in.techware.lataxi.net.utils.WSConstants;

public class RegistrationInvoker extends BaseInvoker {

    public RegistrationInvoker() {
        super();
    }

    public RegistrationInvoker(HashMap<String, String> urlParams,
                               JSONObject postData) {
        super(urlParams, postData);
    }

    public AuthBean invokeRegistrationWS() {

        System.out.println("POSTDATA>>>>>>>" + postData);

        WebConnector webConnector;

        webConnector = new WebConnector(new StringBuilder(ServiceNames.USER_REGISTRATION), WSConstants.PROTOCOL_HTTP, null, postData);

        String wsResponseString = webConnector.connectToPOST_service();

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> response: " + wsResponseString);
        AuthBean authBean = null;
        if (wsResponseString.equals("")) {

            return authBean = null;
        } else {
            authBean = new AuthBean();
            RegistrationParser registrationParser = new RegistrationParser();
            authBean = registrationParser.parseRegistrationResponse(wsResponseString);
            return authBean;
        }
    }
}
```

RegistrationTask.java

```
    package in.techware.lataxi.net.WSAsyncTasks;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import in.techware.lataxi.model.AuthBean;
import in.techware.lataxi.net.invokers.RegistrationInvoker;

public class RegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, AuthBean> {

    private RegistrationTaskListener registrationTaskListener;

    private JSONObject postData;

    public RegistrationTask(JSONObject postData) {
        super();
        this.postData = postData;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthBean doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>doInBackground");
        RegistrationInvoker registrationInvoker = new RegistrationInvoker(null, postData);
        return registrationInvoker.invokeRegistrationWS();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AuthBean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null)
            registrationTaskListener.dataDownloadedSuccessfully(result);
        else
            registrationTaskListener.dataDownloadFailed();
    }

    public static interface RegistrationTaskListener {

        void dataDownloadedSuccessfully(AuthBean authBean);

        void dataDownloadFailed();
    }

    public RegistrationTaskListener getRegistrationTaskListener() {
        return registrationTaskListener;
    }

    public void setRegistrationTaskListener(RegistrationTaskListener registrationTaskListener) {
        this.registrationTaskListener = registrationTaskListener;
    }
}
```

Help please? Not exactly sure how to work with JSONObjects, in the process of learning but still new to me

Comment: Can you also add your `wsResponseString` to the question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I found this one that might be what you mean:

Comment: See this line `System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> response: " + wsResponseString);` what does it print in your log statements?

Comment: Oh I think I see, here is the few couple lines above the error: ` I/System.out: POSTDATA>>>>>>>{""}
11-05 01:54:59.785 in.techware.lataxi I/System.out: >>>>>>>>>url : http://******/
11-05 01:54:59.805 in.techware.lataxi I/WebConnector: connectToPOST_service: encoded String : 
11-05 01:55:00.175 in.techware.lataxi I/System.out: >>>>>>>>>>Stringbuilder response:  {"status":"error","message":null,"error":"501"}
11-05 01:55:00.175 in.techware.lataxi I/System.out: >>>>>>>>>>> response:  {"status":"error","message":null,"error":"501"}`

Comment: You say this app was created for you ? You should contact the programmer/company again.

Answer (score 0):

Below particular part of your RegistrationParser.java file is expecting the value of "error" key in response to be a json object again. However the response contains a string value "501" for this "error" key. Hence it's throwing a jsonexception.

```
if (jsonObj.has("error")) {
                JSONObject errorJSObj;
                try {
                    errorJSObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("error");
                    if (errorJSObj != null) {
                        if (errorJSObj.has("message")) {
                            authBean.setErrorMsg(errorJSObj.optString("message"));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                authBean.setStatus("error");
            }
}
```

Essentially, error code 501 means that you have not yet implemented the part where your user gets created and so your webservice is throwing this error instead of a 200 code. Also, the way you are parsing your response in case of any network error is different from the actual error response sent by your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject errorJSObj;   
try {
                errorJSObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("error");
```

Probably you get string from response not json object. Try to find actual Json Objects are there inside jsonObj value. Log JsonObj.